# Can I run queries on beta sites?

Tags: support, data-explorer

https://data.stackexchange.com/ will let me run queries on launched sites, but is there a way to run queries on betas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the beta sites aren't part of the [monthly data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), which is what SEDE uses to run queries. The beta sites do have the same API (at api.foo.stackexchange.com) as launched sites; you can use that to get some of the same data